# Why is my Scraper Pulling Text as though I'm not Logged In?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm using log in credentials to access the pricing of a specific webpage. However, my code is pulling "See My Price" instead of the actual price (as if I'm not logged in). The Chrome session driver shows me logged in and if I do a Ctrl+U on the page, the price is visible. Why is it pulling data as though I'm not signed in? Thanks.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.example.com')
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign In or Register").click()
driver.find_element_by_name('UserName').send_keys("usr")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_name('Password').send_keys("pwd")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton").click()


search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('Example Text')
WebDriverWait(search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN), 10)
time.sleep(10)

with urlopen(driver.current_url) as response:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    pageList = soup.find('div', 'price').getText()
    print(pageList)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Please explain...

Comment: Either the website does not show you as logged in or bs is grabbing a element that is not visible to the user. Try running in non headless mode to see which is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing:

```
with urlopen(driver.current_url) as response:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    pageList = soup.find('div', 'price').getText()
    print(pageList)
```

with:

```
response = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
pageList = soup.find('div', 'price').getText()
print(pageList)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it pulling data as though I'm not signed in?

You are calling `urlopen`, which makes another HTTP request.  This request knows nothing about the previous login request via selenium and does not contain the cookies that were set on login.  Therefore, the response returned is from a session that is not logged in.